# Why does this mocha test timeout when using a simple call with mongoose?

Tags: typescript, asynchronous, mongoose, mocha.js, chai

I am trying to make a simple assertion on an async db method:

```js
describe('User Repository', () => {
  describe('findById', () => {
    it('Returns a user that exists in the db by id', async () => {
      const fakeUserId = "62ce9f5066cd11e576a3deb3"
      const user = await UserRepository.findUserById(ukUserId)
      expect(user._id).to.equal("62ce9f5066cd11e576a3deb3")
    })
  })
})
```

The method being tested:

```js
import {Types} from 'mongoose';
import {User} from '../../models/users.model';
import {UserDocument} from '../../interfaces/mongoose.gen';

class UserRepository {
  static findUserById = async (
    userId: Types.ObjectId | string,
  ): Promise<UserDocument | null> => User.findById(userId)
}

export default UserRepository;
```

This leads to a timeout error:

```
Error: Timeout of 5000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:559:17)
    at processTimers (node:internal/timers:502:7)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that this works:

```js
it('Returns a user that exists in the db by id', (done) => {
      const ukUserId = "62ce9f5066cd11e576a3deb3"
      UserRepository.findUserById(ukUserId).then(user => {
        expect(user._id).to.equal("62ce9f5066cd11e576a3deb3")
        expect(user.email).to.equal("ukcustomer@example.com")
        expect(user.password).to.equal("password")
        expect(user.first_name).to.equal("John")
        expect(user.last_name).to.equal("Doe")
      })
      done()
    })
```

However it would be great if anyone knows how to do the equivalent using `async/await` also!